# populate combobox1 depending to another combobox2

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, winforms

I want to fill the combobox2 but taking into account the value chosen on combobox1;
for example if one chooses value 1 of combobox1; automatically combobox2 will be filled with the values "a" and "b"....

```
private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        int selectedIndex = combobox1.SelectedIndex;


        if (selectedIndex == 1)
        {
            combobox1.Items.Clear();
            combobox1.Items.Add(" a");
            combobox1.Items.Add("b");            
        }

        else if (selectedIndex == 2)
        {
            combobox2.Items.Clear();
            combobox2.Items.Add("c");
            combobox2.Items.Add("d");           
        }
    }
```

this error is showing :

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
> Parameter name: SelectedIndex'

if anyone has any idea they help us solve this problem; thanks

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my test, you can try the following code to fill another combobox based on the current combobox.

Also, If you need to use too much `if` statement, I suggest that you can try `switch..case` statement.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test4");

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0:
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("a");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("b");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("c");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("d");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("e");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("f");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("g");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("h");
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Index");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the combobox's item index starts at 0. You need to make the following changes:

```
 private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    int selectedIndex = combobox1.SelectedIndex;


    if (selectedIndex == 0) 
    {
        combobox1.Items.Clear();
        combobox1.Items.Add(" a");
        combobox1.Items.Add("b");            
    }

    else if (selectedIndex == 1)
    {
        combobox2.Items.Clear();
        combobox2.Items.Add("c");
        combobox2.Items.Add("d");           
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it work for me

Comment: @issam jallal, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark the useful reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.